# Почему параметры не применяются к картинке в стилях, а в самом теге img - применяются. От чего это может зависеть?

Tags: html, css

Так не работает

```
<style>

    .map {
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

А так работает

```
<img class="map"  src="images/treasuremap.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё работает.

```css
.map {
   width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="map"  src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper-big.jpg" alt="">
```

Если не работает - проверьте внимательно синтаксис, сами параметры, совпадают ли классы и пр. Так же, возможно стили перезаписываются другими, это с помощью инспектора кода выявить можно в любом браузере